# AWS CLI version 1 update suppression list for SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

We have the older AWS CLI client running on our instances. With this tool we can't update our suppression list for SES.
want to know about the requirements that new CLI has and if it is fully backwards compatible?

Alternatively, if there is a way to get the suppression list updated aside from that can be use!!

Comment: Please redefine your question so it's clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PutAccountSuppressionAttributes operation in the Amazon SES API v2 to enable and set up the account-level suppression list. This does not exist in the API V1 version of SES

While AWS CLI v2 is mostly backwards compatible with AWS CLI v1, there are some backwards incompatible changes which are listed in our AWS CLI v2 migration guide.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cliv2-migration.html

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-cli-v2-is-now-generally-available/

Requirements, not sure what you mean, but it's using python underlying.

Comment: Hello, Lucasz thanks!

We have the older AWS CLI client running on our instances. With this tool we can't update our suppression list for SES. want to know about the requirements that new CLI has and if it is fully backwards compatible? 

Alternatively, if there is a way to get the suppression list updated aside from that can be use!!

Comment: Not fully backwards compatibility. You can use the SDK to update that list too. Is available in python, node, .net,... You might look into what I have send and check if there are things that will stop.working after upgrade and fix them. You can also install 2 Aws cli's but use one with alias so you have both running but only use the newer CLI for updating the list